# scroll-preserve-screen-position screws up evil-scroll-down (C-d) in evil

Tags: evil, scrolling

centered-cursor-mode has been extremely sluggish so I found that this setup achieves the same without the slowness:

```
(setq scroll-preserve-screen-position t
      scroll-conservatively 0
      maximum-scroll-margin 0.5
      scroll-margin 99999)
```

The only problem is C-d in Evil mode scrolls to the bottom of the screen and not half screen like before. C-u performs as expected (scrolls half screen up).

I checked the key binding of C-d and it still shows up as (evil-scroll-down count) as expected.
Not sure how to fix that.